Не получается запустить контейнер в Docker
ОС:windows 10
Docker Image:Server: Docker Desktop 4.31.1, Version: 26.1.4;
Не запускается контейнер.Выходит ошибка:
Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/kvm": no such file or directory.
Virtualization включена на компьютере
Логи
docker run -d -p 6080:6080 -e EMULATOR_DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S10" -e WEB_VNC=true --device /dev/kvm --name android-container budtmo/docker-android:emulator_11.0
docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/kvm": no such file or directory.


судя по всему, виртуализация всё-таки не доступна виртуальной машине.

@aleksandrbarakin другие контейнеры работают исправно, почему то именно при попытке запустить этот выходит эта ошибка

при запуске других процессов вы же, вероятно, не указываете явно использовать это устройство: --device /dev/kvm

к сведению

Виртуализация в Docker Desktop не работает на Windows, только на Linux.
Если убрать KVM, то будет работать медленно.
